# Odoo Sales Order import results in wrong product line items

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When I import a Sales Order, the resulting Quotation displays the wrong product. Here is the process I followed

Import a new customer with the following csv file which works as expected:

```
id,property_account_payable_id/id,property_account_receivable_id/id,notify_email,active,company_id/id,company_type,name 
TestCustomer,__export__.account_account_15,__export__.account_account_7,All Messages,TRUE,base.main_company,Company,Test Customer
```

Import a new product, which works as expected:

```
id,active,description,categ_id/id,name,price,type,uom_po_id/id,uom_id/id,list_price,state
ABCDEF123456,TRUE,ABCDEF123456 Description,product.product_category_all,ABCDEF123456 Name,123,consu,product.product_uom_unit,product.product_uom_unit,453.67,
```

Import a new sales order, which does **NOT** works as expected:

```
id,partner_id/id,order_line/product_id/id,order_line/product_uom_qty
SalesOrder123456,TestCustomer,ABCDEF123456,1
```

Here is the export of the result of importing the sales order csv above:

```
"id","partner_id/id","order_line/product_id/id","order_line/product_uom_qty"
"SalesOrder123456","TestCustomer","__export__.product_product_13639","1.0"
```

If I go into Settings > Sequences & Identifiers > External Identifiers and search for "13639", I get a result of a completely different product which was imported earlier.

Anybody have any idea what is going on here? This seems like a bug in the import process.

Comment: are you trying to import sales order invoices?

Comment: No, Sales Orders. From the main menu, I am going to Sales > Sales Orders > Import

Comment: How did you import the product? Do you use product variants in Odoo (has to be activated in the settings)? If not you probably have imported on model `product.template` but Odoo should not import your sales order then.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using csv for import,you can use pgadmin(postgresql gui tool).Just select your database name and in the top you can see sql enabled,click it and issue an sql query(you must know the table name which you want to retreive) after that you can export it and import in your desired DB.

Comment: It was not stated why he is using csv import/export, but i guess he is using it, because he can't connect to the database directly or has no idea how to do that. So either this answer is not helpful or not helpful enough, because you did not provide information how to connect and how to fulfill his case. downvoted